# Symmetric group square

Tags: group-theory

Let G be the symmetry group of T, where T is a square.

Find all the elemnts of G and find generators and relations for G.

This is my notation:

$x_1$ reflection about y-axis
$x_2$ reflection about x-axis
$x_3$ reflection about y = -x
$x_4$ reflection about y = x
$y_{90}$ rotation about origin of 90
$y_{180}$ rotation about origin of 180
$y_{270}$ rotation about origin of 270

So for finding the elements, I said let $x = x_1$ and $y = y_1$ then

$y_{180} = y^2$, $y_{270} = y^3$
$x_2 = xy^2$
$x_3 = xy$
$x_4 = xy^3$

so $G = sym(T) = \{e,x,y,y^2,y^3,xy,xy^2,xy^3\}$, where x and y are generators

I have a query here, couldn't $x_2$ also be a generator? How would I overcome this (I've never dealt with something like this before).

Finally, could someone explain how I can go about finding the relations? I don't know what this actually means but from a quick search it means defining the whole group with some elements? so far I have $y^4 = e$ and $x^2 = e$ but how would I go about getting the others?

Comment: @JonathanY. My apologies, I've removed the tag.

Comment: Note that generators are elements whose powers and products of powers generate the group. If $a$ and $b$ generate the group, then $a$, $b$ and $c$ definitely generate it. It is possible that $a$ and $b$ generate the group; and so do $a$ and $c$.